# Trying to build a pie chart in Kendo-ui-angular2. Pie chart is displayed but not labels

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Component code is as below and the html code. I am using `[data] = "item.data"` `[name] = "item.name"` to bind the data

```
private series: any[] = [{
    name: ["India","Aus", "Fin"],
    data: [3.907, 7.943, 7.848]
}];

<kendo-chart>
    <kendo-chart-title text="Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/">
    </kendo-chart-title>
    <kendo-chart-legend position="top" orientation="horizontal">
    </kendo-chart-legend>
    <kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0}%">
    </kendo-chart-tooltip>
    <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of series" type="donut" [data]="item.data" [name]="item.name">
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
    </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<kendo-chart>
    <kendo-chart-title text="Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/">
    </kendo-chart-title>
    <kendo-chart-legend position="top" orientation="horizontal">
    </kendo-chart-legend>
    <kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0}%">
    </kendo-chart-tooltip>
    <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of series" type="donut" [data]="item.data" [name]="item.name">
            <kendo-chart-series-item-labels>
            </kendo-chart-series-item-labels>
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
    </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

Within the `<kendo-chart-series-item-labels>` tag, you can use properties such as: position, "above" "below" "center" "insideEnd" "left" "outsideEnd" "right"; [distance], any number but 20 is usually a decent amount; format, Uses the IntlService format method.

--EDIT--

It's not quite what you asked for but this way, you cant atleast see the Names of each segment:

```
<kendo-chart>
    <kendo-chart-title text="Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/">
    </kendo-chart-title>
    <kendo-chart-legend position="top" orientation="horizontal">
    </kendo-chart-legend>
    <kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0}%">
    </kendo-chart-tooltip>
    <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item type="donut" [data]="series" field="data" categoryField="name">
            <kendo-chart-series-item-labels visible="true" content="categoryField">
            </kendo-chart-series-item-labels>
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
    </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>

private series: any[] = [{
    name: "India",
    data: 3.907
}, {
    name: "Aus",
    data: 7.943
}, {
    name: "Fin",
    data: 7.848
}];
```

- Feel free to join the Kendo UI slack team: https://kendouiangular2.slack.com/

Comment: I tried doing that. But the values are displayed as labels but not the actual labels.

Comment: What does it display and what should it display?

Comment: It is displaying 3.907, 7.943, 7.848 as labels. I am trying to display the labels as "India","Aus", "Fin". You can see how I am binding the data in the above code.